# gvnccapture- Installation

Tags: vnc, screenshot, xen

I want to capture virtual machine screenshot. I have installed xen hypervisor and I am controlling my virtual machines using libvirt-php API. It has a function:

> libvirt_domain_get_screenshot($res);

When I execute it output:

> Warning: libvirt_domain_get_screenshot() [function.libvirt-domain-get-screenshot]: Cannot find gvnccapture binary in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/myvms/vnc.php on line 9

So, I need to install gvnccapture binary. Anyone knows how to get it using apt-get or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [gvncviewer [image: Install gvncviewer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gvncviewer) package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gvncviewer
```